# Are my opponents unable to cast spells for the rest of the game if I cast an Epic spell with Hive Mind on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a question about the interaction between cards with the "[Epic](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Epic#Rules)" mechanic and [Hive Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHive%20Mind%5d).

Since the Epic ability happens on resolution instead of casting, that means if the original spell is copied, those copies will be epic as well.  If I have hive mind out and cast something like [Enduring Ideal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnduring%20Ideal%5d), my opponents will be forced to copy it as well.

**Does this mean that as long as my original cast isn't countered, all my opponents will be stuck with an epic ability and are unable to cast for the rest of the game?**

If so, this seems like a powerful combo that could shut down most opponent decks, while you (having expected this outcome) pull a million enchantments out of your deck.

Comment: Be careful about using the word "triggers" here; the Epic ability isn't something that "triggers on resolution"; it's just an effect of the spell resolving. "Trigger" is reserved for a specific meaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Correct, Hive Mind gives every player a copy of the Epic spell. No player for whom it resolves will be able to play spells for the rest of the game.**

Since Hive Mind copies the applicable spells without limitation, these copies of e.g. Enduring Ideal will have the Epic ability and no player for whom it resolves will be able to play any more spells that game.

Only the copies made by the Epic ability itself do not have the Epic ability. Therefore, you could also use any other spell or ability to copy an Epic spell and get that many copies each turn, e.g. through [Chandra, the Firebrand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20the%20Firebrand%5d)

Comment: FWIW: We discussed when you yourself copy epic spells previously:  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/what-happens-when-you-copy-an-epic-spell/23295#23295

Comment: Also note that if Hive Mind is already on the field, countering the original Epic spell won't do anything to the copies, as they are created on cast. You'd need to counter or remove them individually.